# Sinch logout message handling

Tags: sinch

while user login to his account Sinch send all  the previous message of that user on login.received only new message and undelivered message ,not previous messages

Answer (score 1):

As long as you dont delete any local databases and you login to the app using your security you should not recieve them. Sinch doesnt have a "logout" function.

If you uninstall its considered to be a new device and we deliver the messages to that device.

SO on logout when you delete files on your device make sure you just delete your files. (dont delete the sinch folder)

Comment: How do you check if it's a new device? Do you use some kind of NSUserDefaults? Can you tell, what's the key then?

Comment: its uuidfor vendor and saved data. Havind said that we only save messages for delivery for 30 days, so we dont replay messages for ever. So you should save it to a local database or remote.